# how to arrange an array in decreasing order

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, iteration, decrease-key

I have a simple code to iterate over all the elements within the range

```
for i in range(5,10):
    print(i)
#output
5
6
7
8
9
```

Now, would it be possible to iterate the same elements from 10 to 5 in the decreasing order ?
By changing the range in the above code from 10 to 5 won't work

```
 for i in range(10,5):
        print(i)
    #output not printed and no error displayed
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like

```py
for i in range(10,0,-1):
    print(i)
```

The `-1` here is saying that we are taking steps of `-1` instead of the 1 that is default.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [reversed](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#reversed) builtin method

```
for i in reversed(range(5, 10)):
    print(i)
```

An other  option is to set `step` in range loop like `range(10, 5, -1)`